# How do you make a text in a div wrap around another div with img and text in it

Tags: html, css, css-float

How do you make a text in a div wrap around another div and float or inline-block is not working.
This is what I want.

```
                      ________
_____________________|        |_
 Div: text text text |  img   | |
 text test text text |separate| |
 text test text text |   div  | |
 text test text text  --------  |
text test text text text test   |
```

This is what I have.

```
                      ________
_____________________|        |_
 Div: text text text |  img   | |
 text test text text |separate| |
 text test text text |   div  | |
 text test text text  --------  |
text test text text             |
text test text text             |
text test text text             |
```

Answer (score 2):

This should really be quite straight forward. Just float the `div` or `img` and apply a negative `margin`.

```css
body{background: red;}

div {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  background: #fff;
}

img {
  float: right;
  margin: -20px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut laoreet massa nec massa commodo pretium. Proin vehicula enim ultrices nibh cursus commodo. Morbi orci
  purus, posuere vel erat sit amet, viverra condimentum velit. Ut tincidunt mi ac ornare finibus. In vehicula, dolor ut rutrum egestas, lorem orci pulvinar velit, vel rutrum urna massa et augue. Integer vel dapibus diam. Quisque lorem sem, feugiat sed
  accumsan non, condimentum vel est. Sed at ipsum nec eros pellentesque ullamcorper sed a eros. In in posuere dui. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque interdum, arcu eu congue lobortis, est metus consectetur tellus, nec sollicitudin justo mauris vehicula nunc.
  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ppadding/ margin - I have set us a code pen here:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cord-codes/pen/mmVqGZ)

**HTML**

```
    <div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2rju9r765Nbqd7MKVb2EGuAomXXBMqM5pBEhhLFiCnSjuP9R1eLLh5sU"/>
  </div>
  texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br/>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext<br/>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext<br/>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext<br/>texttexttexttexttexttexttext
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one{
  width:550px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
  margin-top:50px;
  padding-right:100px;
  word-wrap:word-break;
}
.two{
  float:right;
  margin-right:-60px;
  margin-top:-40px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make them two separate divs and apply float to the first div with a fixed width and height. that is:

HTML

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b">TEXT TEXT TEXT<div>
```

Then in your CSS

```
.a {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bc367xnb/27/)